# Nativescript - cannot upload ipa file to itunes

Tags: app-store-connect, nativescript

I'm doing the following to upload my ipa file to itunes connect.

`tns publish ios MY-ITUNES-ACCOUNT-EMAIL APP-SPECIFIC-PASSWORD -ipa app.ipa`

I'm getting the following error - in red

`{
  "serviceErrors" : [ {
    "code" : "-20101",
    "message" : "Your Apple ID or password was incorrect."
  } ]
}`

This used to work - about 2-3 weeks ago.

Comment: Try to generate new APP-SPECIFIC-PASSWORD

Comment: I did that. I've got 2-factor-authen enabled also. but the cli doesn't prompt for the code.

Comment: just use tns publish ios --ipa ''path to ipa", don't supply username/password inline command

Comment: When it's APP-SPECIFIC-PASSWORD, cli doesn't promt for code.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion - still the same. I generated password again - and copy/pasted. I'm on CLI 5.3.4 - is this working for you?

Comment: yes, it is working for me with version  5.3.1

Comment: I moved back to 5.3.1 and it works now. Nativescript...one step forward...two step backwards. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to be problem with tns cli version. Stick to version `5.3.1` for now solves the issue.

Comment: how do you downgrade to 5.3.1

Comment: npm i -g nativescript@5.3.1

Comment: I confirm that 5.4.0 version contains this bug.

Comment: Does anybody have news on this? Migrated to {N} 6 yesterday and I still am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think `tns publish ios` command has been changed a bit for NativeScript 6. I can publish my apps like this now:

```
tns publish ios myuser@mydomain.com --appleApplicationSpecificPassword xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx --ipa myapp.ipa
```

You should change the values with your information, of course.

With this command, you will be prompted to enter you Apple ID password and 6 digit 2FA code. After that, the upload will start and finish as you expected.

Finally, here is the official documentation: https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/publishing/publish-ios